# Printing all elements (NSString) from two 2 NSArray (Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to NSLog all the elements from two NSArray and append them. But I don't know how to do it.
For example, I have a NSArray with at index 0: "My name is" and at index: 1 "Your name is"
and another NSArray with at index: 0 "Peter", at index:1 "Kate" and at index:2 "Jack"
I would like to print all the possibilities at once:

My name is Peter

My name is Kate

My name is Jack

Your name is Peter

Your name is Kate

Your name is Jack

Comment: this is static/constant or dynamically used

Comment: it is dynamic. the words are randoms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your first array is `sentenceBeginnings` and your second array is `names`:

```
for (NSString *text in sentenceBeginnings) {
    for (NSString *name in names) {
        NSLog(@"%@ %@", text, name);
    }
}
```

Each element in the array is assigned to a variable (`text` or `name`) and the code inside each set of brackets is executed once per element.